# libpcap on OSX - trying to use statistical mode

Tags: macos, pcap, winpcap, libpcap, packet-sniffers

I'm trying to compile a C program that uses libpcap in [statistical mode](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_41b5/html/group__wpcap__tut9.html) on OSX. The original code was written for Windows, using the winpcap library. The version of libpcap on my Mac has never heard of the [pcap_setmode](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_41b5/html/group__wpcapfunc.html#gef07ef49d3c75644f3fd34518e2fe720) function that it uses - I've got a nasty feeling that it might be Windows-specific.

Is there any way to capture in stats-mode on OSX? If not, is there something about the architecture/capabilities of the OS that prevents this, or is this an extra feature added to WinPcap  which has never been a feature of the main library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pcap_setmode()` only has a definition in the Win32 port, because the WinPcap driver for Windows is the only packet capture mechanism that supports statistical mode; BPF in Mac OS X and *BSD and AIX and Solaris 11 don't support it, PF_PACKET sockets in Linux don't support it, DLPI in Solaris and HP-UX don't support it, etc..

UN*Xes generally come with a mechanism that supports capturing packets, so libpcap can just use that, without adding its own kernel-mode code; this means it can't control what facilities those capture mechanisms have - if a capture mechanism doesn't have it, libpcap can't add it.  Windows doesn't come with such a mechanism; it does come with NDIS, which can support such a mechanism, so WinPcap comes with a kernel-mode driver that uses NDIS to implement such a mechanism, and thus has some more control over what features it offers.

Answer (score 1):

`pcap_setmode()` only has a definition in the Win32 port (for unknown reasons to me).